# EntityRef and compiled LINQ plans

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Is there any way to force LINQ-2-SQL to compile and cache plans for [EntityRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348960.aspx).

From internal profiling we are seeing a significant amount of CPU used to keep on recompiling plans.

```
System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.Compile
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.GetReaderFactory
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Compile
System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices+DeferredSourceFactory`1.ExecuteKeyQuery
System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices+DeferredSourceFactory`1.Execute
System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault
System.Data.Linq.EntityRef`1.get_Entity
```

I would prefer to use entity ref, but I guess if there is no choice we can hand code this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to force LINQ 2 SQL to compile and caches queries for EntityRef or EntitySet.

There are no hooks in the implementation for it.

If you need to use [CompiledQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932594/when-should-i-use-a-compiledquery) you will have to write your own wrapper and helpers.